# Angular2 Material Design

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have installed Angular2 Material Design and the libraries sit in the directory

```
node_modules/angular2-material
```

When I try to import any component from angular2-material I get (on the browser) the following error

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM3502:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js as "@angular2-material/toolbar" from http://localhost:4200/app/pfa-platform.component.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

I have the following system-config.ts

```
/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  '@angular2-material': 'vendor/@angular2-material',
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  '@angular2-material/core': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  },
  '@angular2-material/sidenav': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'sidenav.js'
  },
  '@angular2-material/toolbar': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'toolbar.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

package.json is

```
{
  "name": "pfa-platform",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.14",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tslint": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if anybody could point me at the error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem was very simple. I did not update `angular-cli-build.js` and therefore there was no `@angular2-material` in the `dist` directory.